# Set specific nav bar color?

Tags: ios

I was using

```
//declared in viewcontroller.m
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]

//super view did load
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x9ff1d1)];

//above view did load
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

to set the nav bar color in my app and it worked. After updating to iOS 8 I think it must have been deprecated. Is there way to set the nav bar color to  hex color:0x9ff1d1)];